# SQL function to check multiple condition with datetime column and perform addition based on condition using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make sql function to perform calculation as per below logic. I am using phpmyadmin and this is what I tried so far. I am geeting syntax error.

Logic I want to implement :

```
if((column A == null) && (column B == null)){

                 return null;
             }

             var C = moment(column A).add(98, 'days'); 
             var D = moment(column B).add(98, 'days'); 

            

              
                if(column B == null)
                {
                    return C.format('DD MMM YYYY'); // Add 98 Days 
                }

        
                else     
                {
                    return D.format('DD MMM YYYY'); // Add 98 Days
                }

   
            }
```

This is what I done so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TssaForecast(A DATETIME, B DATETIME) RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN

  DECLARE TID DATETIME;
    

IF ( (A is NULL) AND (B is NULL) ) THEN
    SET TID = ' ';

ELSE IF (A is NULL) THEN
    SET TID = DATE_ADD( B, INTERVAL 98 DAY);
    
ELSE 
    SET TID = DATE_ADD( A, INTERVAL 98 DAY);
    
END IF;

    RETURN TID;
    
END
```

Please advice what is wrong in this code. Thank you.

Comment: `SET TID = ' '` is not a valid datetime. Why not use `NULL`?

Comment: What is the exact error message? What line is the syntax error on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic in code and SQL is different. In your code B is preferred over A if both A and B are supplied, whereas your SQL code prefers A over B.

In any case, you don't really need a function for this, it's fairly simple: `DATE_ADD(COALESCE(A, B), INTERVAL 98 DAY)` (here A is preferred over B).

`COALESCE` will return first non-NULL argument it is supplied or NULL if all of them are NULL and then 98 will get added to that (adding an interval to NULL will result in a NULL).

If you need it as a function really then:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TsaaForecast(A DATETIME, B DATETIME)
RETURNS DATETIME DETERMINISTIC
RETURN DATE_ADD(COALESCE(A, B), INTERVAL 98 DAY)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f087a427bbfdc7565af3d2d4ef88497)*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry for confusion in above logic. but COALESCE will also work on multiple condition ? Here is my another Logic that I have to use to make another sql function. This is datatables Render function I used to implement this logic on client side. I have to make sql function to perform same logic.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9ve4rj8m/

@MarcinJ  Here is the link to my Logic which has multiple condition. I have to make sql function because I need to show result of this function on charts using COUNT.

Comment: Yes, although in this case you're probably better off using a `CASE WHEN x IS NOT NULL THEN DATE_ADD(..., however many days)` and so on because you have different number of days to add depending on which date is actually supplied.

Comment: You need to learn some SQL syntax before you attempt writing SQL code my man. You don't need a variable or anything, just RETURN CASE ... END (no AS or anything, just a case statement.